# JNA How to use HWND_BROADCAST

Tags: java, jna

I need use HWND_BROADCAST value for SHAppBarMessage in java

Although this [document](http://jna.java.net/javadoc/platform/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/W32API.html) says it exists in jna i cant reach it when i write W32API in netbeans. I already import the platformjar and jna.jar but i cant reach it. How can i reach it?

Comment: Make sure that JNA's `platform.jar` is included in your project.  Netbeans should be able to find it from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to find it in [WinUser](http://twall.github.com/jna/3.5.1/javadoc/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/WinUser.html#HWND_BROADCAST), at least in version 3.5.1 on.